# SSD partition only shows after navigating to in Nautlius -- disables instant linking

Tags: dual-boot, navigation

I have this issue in which an SSD partition (shared storage for dual booting Windows & Linux) only shows up in `/media` after navigating to it in other locations in Nautilus file explorer.

Now, this isn't a huge problem, but it surely has a work around. I have a few application links that try to navigate to a `/media/pathtofile`, which obviously doesn't work if it hasn't shown up yet. The path (`/dev/something`) to storage as seen here doesn't show up when I try to browse it here either:

[image: storage path]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds as if that partition is treated as a removable disk (the `/media` mount point is another hint), not as a regular filesystem.

You will probably need to add an entry for that partition to `/etc/fstab`. If there already is one, check if it has the `noauto` option set which prevents automatic mounting.

Comment: Perfect! Completely solved it for me, ended up having to append an entry to fstab. For whoever may come across the same issue, this gave me a lot of information: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Fstab

Comment: @IvanDikmans If this answer solves your problem, please mark it as the solution by clicking the gray checkmark next to it. Thanks!